# Google App Script: Remove blank rows from range selection for sorting

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering, google-sheets-formula

I want to sort real-time when a number is calculated in a "Total" column, which is a sum based on other cells, inputted by the user.  The sort should be descending and I did achieve this functionality using the following:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var columnToSortBy = 6;
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );

}
```

It's short and sweet, however empty cells in the total column which contain the following formula, blanking itself if the sum result is a zero, otherwise printing the result:

```
=IF(SUM(C2:E2)=0,"",SUM(C2:E2))
```

It causes these rows with an invisible formula to be included in the range selection and upon descending sort, they get slapped up top for some reason.  I want these blank rows either sorted to the bottom, or in an ideal scenario removed from the range itself (Without deleting them and the formula they contain from the sheet) prior to sorting.

Or maybe some better way which doesn't require me dragging a formula across an entire column of mostly empty rows.  I've currently resorted to adding the formula manually one by one as new entries come in, but I'd rather avoid this.

**EDIT:** Upon request find below a screenshot of the sheet.  As per below image, the 6th column of total points needs to be sorted descending, with winner on top.  This should have a pre-pasted formula running lengthwise which sums up the preceding columns for each participant.

The column preceding it (Points for Tiers) is automatically calculated by multiplying the "Tiers" column by 10 to get final points.  This column could be eliminated and everything shifted once left, but  it's nice to maintain a visual of the actual points awarded.  User input is entered in the 3 white columns.

[image: Sheet sort]

Comment: What is the purpose of the formula? Could you share a screenshot of the sheet showing it's purpose? Is it's purpose to remove 0, if the actual c5:e5 is 1,-1,0 or to be blank, ifc5:e5 is blank and unused at the bottom(is it just a bunch of empty rows at bottom) ?

Comment: @TheMaster Updated question with screenshot.  Tanaike's answer is most of the way there, but formulas are pasted as values which is problematic for the 5th column that serves as a visual of tier points achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to sort the sheet by the column "F" as the descending order.
- You want to sort the sheet by ignoring the empty cells in the column "F".
- You want to move the empty rows to the bottom of row.
- You don't want to change the formulas at the column "F".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, when the empty cells are scattered at the column "F", I think that the built-in method of "sort" of Class Range cannot be directly used. The empty cells are moved to the top of row like your issue. So in this answer, I would like to propose to use the sort method of JavaScript for this situation.

#### Modified script:

In order to run this function, please edit a cell.

```
function onEdit(event){
  const columnToSortBy = 6; // Column "F"
  const headerRow = 1; // 1st header is the header row.
  
  const sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange(1 + headerRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - headerRow, sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .sort((a, b) => a[columnToSortBy - 1] > b[columnToSortBy - 1] ? -1 : 1)
    .reduce((o, e) => {
      o.a.push(e.splice(0, columnToSortBy - 1));
      e.splice(0, 1);
      if (e.length > 0) o.b.push(e);
      return o;
    }, {a: [], b: []});
  sheet.getRange(1 + headerRow, 1, values.a.length, values.a[0].length).setValues(values.a);
  if (values.b.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(1 + headerRow, columnToSortBy + 1, values.b.length, values.b[0].length).setValues(values.b);
  }
}
```

- In this sample script, it supposes that the header row is the 1st row. If in your situation, no header row is used, please modify to `const headerRow = 0;`.
- From your question, I couldn't understand about the columns except for the column "F". So in this sample script, all columns in the data range except for the column "F" is replaced by sorting. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- Please use this sample script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))
- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

### Added:

- You want to sort the sheet by the column "F" as the descending order.
- You want to sort the sheet by ignoring the empty cells in the column "F".

  - You want to move the empty rows to the bottom of row.
- In your situation, there are the values in the column "A" to "F".
- The formulas are included in not only the column "F", but also other columns.
- You don't want to change the formulas.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

From your replying and updated question, I could understand like above. Try this sample script:

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit(event){
  const columnToSortBy = 6; // Column "F"
  const headerRow = 1; // 1st header is the header row.

  const sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange(1 + headerRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - headerRow, 6);
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  const values = range.getValues().sort((a, b) => a[columnToSortBy - 1] > b[columnToSortBy - 1] ? -1 : 1);
  range.setValues(values.map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => formulas[i][j] || c)));
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, your solution does appear to work with the caveat that internal formulas are pasted as values instead.  Is there some way to allow the sorted contents to remain as they were (such as formulas remaining as formulas?)

Comment: @Luponius Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying and updated question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and goal again, I apologize.

Comment: That is exactly it!  Can you please explain the set values line and what's happening in it?  Marking it as answered since this is exactly what I needed, just not quite sure what's happening with the final set values command

Comment: @Luponius Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the script in the last line, here, the arrays of `values` and `formulas` are used in the loop. When the cell has the formula, the formula is put to the same cell of value. By this, the value is replaced to the formula. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) If this explain was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way to fix this is to just change

```
=IF(SUM(C2:E2)=0,"",SUM(C2:E2))
```

to

```
=IF(SUM(C2:E2)=0,,SUM(C2:E2))
```

The cells that are made blank when the sum is zero will then be treated as truly empty and they will be excluded from sort, so only cells with content will appear sorted at the top of the sheet.

Why your original formula doesn't work that way is because using `""` actually causes the cell contain content so it's not treated as a blank cell anymore. You can test this by entering `ISBLANK(F1)` into another cell and check the difference between the two formulas.